# My Heroku build keeps failing and I have no idea why

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

I keep trying to do the last step to deploy my bot on Heroku but it just keeps failing. I don't know why it keeps happening because everything has been working great so far. I'm pretty new to all of this stuff and I just can't figure out why it doesn't want to work. I tried searching around but it doesn't help.

```
Enumerating objects: 2500, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2500/2500), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2395/2395), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2500/2500), 54.90 MiB | 3.67 MiB/s, done.
Total 2500 (delta 570), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 12.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.18.3
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.14.6
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:        
remote:        > @discordjs/opus@0.3.2 install /tmp/build_9bd73166/node_modules/@discordjs/opus
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:        
remote:        sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 126
remote:        npm ERR! @discordjs/opus@0.3.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 126
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the @discordjs/opus@0.3.2 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.C5Y7h/_logs/2020-08-03T21_26_46_714Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
remote:        
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to essential-bot.
remote:
```

Comment: Have you looked at the logs like its suggests?

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure out what;s causing it

Comment: well what does the log say?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you aren't logged in to the CLI of heroku?
Can we see the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the `node_modules` folder then try again.